# Setting up Apache Storm and trying to list the running topologies

Tags: java, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I'm setting up Apache Storm with difficulty. I currently have 3 servers working locally but not working remotely. When I run nimbus or supervisor to set up the servers they run indefinitely (I'm not sure if this is supposed to be the case or not). I have Zookeeper set up on my nimbus server and that looks like the following

```
########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration
    storm.zookeeper.servers:
 - "192.168.2.106"
 # - "192.168.2.105"
 # - "192.168.2.102"

 storm.local.dir: "/home/scix3/apache/storm/data"

 nimbus.host: "192.168.2.106"
 #
```

I only have on instance of Zookeeper (on nimbus). The config file on my two supervisor servers is as follows:

```
########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration
storm.zookeeper.servers:
 - "192.168.2.106"
 - "192.168.2.105"
 - "192.168.2.102"
#
nimbus.host: "192.168.2.106"
storm.local.dir: "/home/scix3/apache/storm/data"
supervisor.slots.ports:
 - 6700
 - 6701
 - 6702
 - 6703
```

When I run the command `$ storm list` I get a message saying that there is no connection to any machine. I don't understand why, since i think my config files are correct. This is the error message

> 854  [main] INFO  backtype.storm.thrift - Connecting to Nimbus at localhost:6627
>   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I'd follow:

- Comment out the 2 **extra zookeeper servers** on the supervisors config file (you said you only have one, the same config as the nimbus)
- Check (or just stop for them while testing) the **firewalls** of all the hosts
- Stop everything and start, in this order:

  1. Zookeeper
  2. Nimbus
  3. UI
  4. Supervisor(s)
- Check the UI, you should see the supervisors there
- **From the nimbus host**, execute `storm list` (now it should work) (it should work from any supervisor host too)
- If you want to use the CLI from any other place, you should configure, at least, the `nimbus.host` IP on the storm config file of that machine

Additional note: when you execute `storm nimbus|supervisor|ui` it **is** supposed to run indefinitely. But, as they are stateless services, you should run them with any "daemonizer" (daemon, supervisord,...; choose one) which will restart them if they stop/crash for any reason.